# GORM query - how to use calculated field in the query and filter according to its value

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, go-gorm

Currently, I have a GORM query that calculates a counter for each table entry using a second table and returns the first table with a new field "locks_total" which doesn't exist in the original.

Now, what I want to achieve is the same table returned (with the new "locks_total" field) but filtered with "locks_total" = 0.

I can't seem to make it happen because it doesn't recognize this field in the table, what can I do to make it happen? is it possible to run the query and then execute the filter on the new result table?

This is how we currently do it-

```golang
txn := dao.postgresManager.DB().Model(&models.SecretMetadataResponse{})

txn.Table(dao.firstTableName + " as s").
        Select("s.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + dao.secondTableName + " as l where s.id = l.secret_id) locks_total ")

var secretsTotal int64
var metadataResponseEntries []models.SecretMetadataResponse

txn = txn.Count(&secretsTotal). // Saving the count before trimming according to the pagination parameters
                Limit(params.Limit).
                Offset(params.Offset).
                Order(constants.FieldName).
                Order(constants.FieldId).
                Find(&metadataResponseEntries)
```

When the `SecretMetadataResponse` contains the `SecretMetadata` which is the same fields as in the table **and** the `LocksTotal` is the new calculated field that we want to have.

```html
type SecretMetadataResponse struct {
    SecretMetadata
    LocksTotal int `json:"locks_total"`
}
```

Thanks in advance :)